# Few objects in Entity Framework's StateManager consuming massive amounts of RAM

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm currently working on developing new features in application used for distributing games between servers. The application is a .Net Core 2.0 application running EF Core 2.0.0. The problem is that Entity Framework is seemingly allocating massive amounts of memory. I have used dotMemory to troubleshooting and it shows that the source for the memory allocation is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.StateManager. The memory increase is fairly linear as it reads the data. Eventually the memory allocated by the application fills up all of the Windows server's available memory, in this case 12gb, causing errors in other services. It seems that the objects in LOH is never garbage collected and it just continues to grow till the memory fills up completely. It strikes me as very odd that this much data is allocated. I know one could i.e. save the data to a file on disk and then free up the memory, but I'm wondering if that is really necessary or if there is some better solution to this problem.

A few images from the troubleshooting in dotMemory:

Image1: https://i.ibb.co/YXZJ0dY/memory-problem1.jpg

Image2: https://i.ibb.co/YRMTfMF/memory-problem2.jpg

Moving files is the core feature of the application, the architecture of the application is quite layered so the structure becomes quite complex. I have therefore tried to combine the solution of this problem with writing additional unit and integration tests. I have managed to recreate the scenario where the memory fills up and objects ends up in the LOH. I have used a production data entity that I loop and add to an in memory database. But even if I'm cloning this entity 10000 times I'm not getting more than about 1GB RAM usage (which is expected since one entity is about 8MB), but this is far the problem in production. So it makes me wonder if object state tracking can really consume this much memory? It's an other company hosting the solution so I don't want to send a new version to them without having found the proper cause of the problem, but recreating the exact problem is a bit tricky. I have tried adding AsNoTracking() in the unit test but it didn't do much difference in the memory allocation (which makes me wonder if this is because it's an in-memory database?).

So I basically wonder if state is the whole problem? And what is the best the way to recreate an issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

This could be being caused by MARS not being activated on your connection string. This issue logged with the EF Core team seems to confirm this could be the problem: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14640